# Open sets in Y where Y is a subspace of the metric space (X,d) with the induced metric

Tags: metric-spaces

I want to prove the following:
Let  $Y\subset X$, where $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $d_Y$ is the induced metric on Y. Show that:
$U\subset Y$ is open in Y if and only if there exists $V\subset X)$ such that $U=V\cap Y$.

Quite frankly, I have no clue how to start the proof as I dont properly know what it means exactly for a set to be open **in Y**. I know what it means for a set to be open in some metric space and it seems that the definition should be quite similar in this case but I can not figure it out.

Comment: A set is open in Y if it is open relative to the induced metric on Y.

Comment: Do you mean in the third line $U=V\cap Y?$

Comment: yes thank you, edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If $U$ is open in $Y$ then for any $u\in U$ there exists $r_u>0$ such that $B_Y(u,r_u)\subset U.$

- Is it $B_X(u,r_u)$ open in $X$?
- Is it $\bigcup_{u\in U}B_X(u,r_u)$ open in $X?$
- What is the intersection of $\bigcup_{u\in U}B_X(u,r_u)$ and $Y?$

Comment: Can you give one more hint for the first question of your hint, you probably spelled it out a lot already but my intuition is completely off here for some reason.

Comment: The set $B_X(u,r_u)=\{x\in X: d(x,u)<r_u$ is open in $X$ because $(X,d)$ is a metric space. Can you describe $B_X(u,r_u)\cap Y?$

Comment: I think it is $B_Y(u,r_u)$

Comment: You're right. What about $\left(\bigcup_{u\in U}B_X(u,r_u)\right)\cap Y?$

Comment: It should be $\cup_{u \in U) B_Y(u,r_u)$

Comment: So, $V=\bigcup_{u\in U}B_X(u,r_u).$

Comment: I cant edit, I meant $ \left(\bigcup_{u\in U}B_Y(u,r_u)$